# Saving data to be shown later

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I'm new at iOS development and I'm following (and modifying) this tutorial: [Table View Tutorial](http://maybelost.com/2011/12/tutorial-storyboard-app-with-core-data/)

What I am trying to do is the following. Once a user has selected what she/he wants in the `UITableView`, it appears a detailed view with a "Add to order" button. Labels are populated through Core Data.

I'm not sure how to save description and quantity (as represented in the figure) and create an order view which displays (later on) all the selections the user has made. Any ideas?

[image: screenshot]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can  create a model that contains all this information, something like -

```
interface MyOrder {

}

 @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
 @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *description;
 @property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger quantity;
```

Now where u want to save it, create an object of this model and save data in the objects. If you want multiple orders then you may create array of orders.
Now after this u can pass these object to next view controllers as a form of property of that view controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save data that could be retrieved later, you can save in two different ways.

In the first case you could save data using (for example) [PropertyList mechanism](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html). Data are saved in flash memory (in iOS filesystem and not in memory).

In the second way, instead, you could create a [Singleton class](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=singleton%20ios&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CEsQFjAE&url=http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html&ei=SnoUT6ivNuH14QTt1tjtAw&usg=AFQjCNHhlZ0nQmh4uRc5momd7VCU65KV-Q) that saves data in memory. Only one istance can exist during application execution. In this case, data are not saved in a permanent way like the first method.

In both situations you can save and retrieve data from every point of your app.
Obviously the first method could be considered more robust than the first one. If the application crashes at some point data aren't lost.

Hope it helps.

Comment: NSUserDefaults can be used to store more or less anything it's only supposed to be used to store preferences. NSUserDefaults is meant for storing user preferences. You can try to use it for other things, but you probably shouldn't.

Comment: Now i had removed that downvote, but as i had earlier mentioned in the situation that is mentioned in the question, always use of data objects is preferred than plist and user defaults. :)

Comment: @RIP Yes you're right. I only suggested different ways to save data. Thank you for your reply. Cheers.